# Ajax not inserting data into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, function

I am trying to insert data into a database with ajax. The problem is that everything works excepting the insertion of data in the database.
When I click the submit button I get the proper message **"You have been subscribed"** just that it doesn't insert the data in the database. And don't understand exactly why.

I have `dbconn.php`

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli($dbhostname, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}
?>
```

`common-functions.php`

```
<?php
  require_once('dbconn.php');
  function subscribe() {
    global $db;
    if(isset($_POST['semail'], $_POST['sname'])) {
      $name = $_POST['sname'];
      $email = $_POST['semail'];
      $db->query("INSERT INTO subscribers (`name`, `email`, 'confirmed') VALUES ('".$db->escape_string($name)."', '".$db->escape_string($email)."', 0)");
      echo "You have been subscribed";
    }
  }
subscribe();
?>
```

`subscribe.php`

HTML

```
  <form name="subscribe" class="subscribe">
    <label class="lablabel">Name:</label><input type="text" class="subscribe-field" id="sname" name="sname"></br>
    <label class="lablabel">Email:</label><input type="text" class="subscribe-field" id="semail" name="semail"> 
    <input type="submit" id="ssub" value="Subscribe">
  </form>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit','.subscribe',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // add here
  e.stopPropagation(); // add here
  $.ajax({ url: 'lib/common-functions.php',
      data: {action: 'subscribe',
        sname: $("#sname").val(),
        semail: $("#semail").val()},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
        alert(output);
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: first of all check the quotes for `'confirmed'`, secondly you should configure and check error log more often

Comment: yep though the weired think is that i tried changing them from ` to ' for all and that did not worked, but worked in oposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes and substitute with backticks here

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO subscribers (`name`, `email`, 'confirmed') 
                                                      ^         ^
```

Comment: Are the backticks even really necessary?

Comment: Yeah no wrong in adding that and it is a good practice actually.. what if without your knowledge you had named a column with mysql reserved word ?

Comment: Good point, I guess I've fallen into a bad habit of not doing it and it hasn't backfired horribly yet.